# Get-AzureRmResourceGroup -detailed not working

Tags: azure, azure-powershell

I am trying to get the list of all resources under my subscription through Azure RM PS cmdlets. As per PS document `Get-AzureRmResourceGroup -detailed` should help. When I try that, I get the below error. Am I missing anything?

```
----------------------------------
*Get-AzureRmResourceGroup : A parameter cannot be found that matches parameter name 'Detailed'.
At line:1 char:26
+ Get-AzureRmResourceGroup -Detailed
+                          ~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [Get-AzureRmResourceGroup], ParameterBindingException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NamedParameterNotFound,Microsoft.Azure.Commands.Resources.GetAzureResourceGroupCommand*
--------------------------------------
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `detailed` parameter for `Get-AzureRmResourceGroup` was removed on Oct 2 2015 in commit [de84df5](https://github.com/Azure/azure-powershell/commit/de84df5868b039d6748549ecb75ab1621ebbe117#diff-183f317cb786e2e13fd01f1ee13a33d3) I believe in version 1.0.2.

> WriteWarning("The Detailed switch parameter is being deprecated and will be removed in a future release.");

Unfortunately there was no replacement for it, it was simply removed as part of the streamlining of the new AzureRM cmdlets.

Answer (score 0):

Almost certainly what the documentation is telling you is that you can learn more about the command by running `Get-Help Get-AzureRmResourceGroup -Detailed`; this will give you more detailed help information in the PS console. The `Get-AzureRmResourceGroup` cmdlet itself does not have a "-Detailed" parameter -- `Get-Help` does.

Comment: Thanks @jbsmith ! The documentation also tells me to use the command to get the list of all resource groups and their details. Looks like the switch is deprecated in the latest version.

Answer (score 0):

Get-AzureRMResource will list all the resources in a subscription.